# threading in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have WPF Application with C# has back-end. I wish to make it a multi threaded one.

It has a combo-box listing different things. And a user can select them asynchronously.

Suppose the combo-box1 contains 1.ABC
2.BCD
3.CDE

The user selects ABC and it starts executing and again if he clicks on BCD before clicking on ABC..

Likethat, I want a multi-threaded wpf application.

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show( "Executing " + newList[ comboBox1.SelectedIndex]  + " test case" );


        this.IsEnabled = false;


        Thread objThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = listofDirs[comboBox1.SelectedIndex] + "\\" + newList[comboBox1.SelectedIndex] + "\\" + @"\bin\Release";
            p.StartInfo.FileName = listofDirs[comboBox1.SelectedIndex] + "\\" + newList[comboBox1.SelectedIndex] + "\\" + @"\bin\Release" + "\\" + newList[comboBox1.SelectedIndex] + ".exe";
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
        });


        objThread.IsBackground = true;

        objThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;

        objThread.Start();


        this.IsEnabled = true;





    }
```

Comment: I want to know how we can do it ?? The above code is getting some run-time error

Comment: Maybe you should tell us your error or what problem you are running into?

Comment: Stack Overflow is based on people asking questions. Yours is not a question. You're stating what you want and you're posting some code. Also, it is always a good idea to at least provide the error message instead of saying "the code is throwing some runtime error". If you take your car to be repaired, you're telling the mechanics about the symptoms you're experiencing, right? You're not just telling them "car doesn't work as expected"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again: *You can not access UI controls from any other thread than the thread which created them.* If you want to do so, you need to use `Control.Invoke` for Windows Forms or `Dispatcher.Invoke` for WPF.

In your case, your thread tries to access the index of the item selected in the `ComboBox`, which is an invalid cross thread operation. Move that out of your thread method and you're set.

Comment: This "I access a control from another thread and get an exception" thing is getting old... Can't we have a bot that post this answer every time a question is tagged "wpf" and "multithreading" ?